# How to come out of error-org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using spring security core plug in in my grails app. When I run the app, I'm getting following error. How can I solve this?

```
Configuring Spring Security ...
2011-06-30 10:45:19,468 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objecthospitalmanagement.Physician
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objecthospitalmanagement.Physician
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objecthospitalmanagement.Physician
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objecthospitalmanagement.Physician
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objecthospitalmanagement.Physician
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    ... 23 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Patient for class: hospitalmanagement.Physician
    at hospitalmanagement.Physician.<init>(Physician.groovy)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Patient for class: hospitalmanagement.Physician
    at hospitalmanagement.Physician.<init>(Physician.groovy)
```

This is telling you that `hospitalmanagement.Physician` is trying to access a `Patient` property which doesn't exist (in the same class).

No idea how you should solve that since you haven't shown the corresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution at the link below. It worked for me.
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120786-Upgraded-from-Grails-1-3-7-to-2-0-and-am-getting-method-lt-init-gt-%28%29V-not-found-error&p=409849#post409849